# Scraping with multiple IP, in java

Tags: java, web-scraping

Well basically I have a scraping application.
It scrapes around n items per minute.
currently i have only one IP.

The site i'm scraping allows me 3 connections per IP.

I'm thinking about getting another IP.

so i'll be able to get 6 connections.

in theory i should be able to get n items in 40 seconds, more or less.

currently i'm using java (commons-httpcore) to get the job done.

I'm not sure if this is java question or an OS question.

my machine has IP 1 and IP 2
how do i connect to, say, www.microsoft.com,
using IP 1 and using IP2?
how can i specify, which ip i want to use to do a connection?

Comment: Has it occurred to you that they limit the number of connections per IP because they don't want you doing something like this?

Comment: Has this been downvoted simply because this is about webpage-scraping? (Which is not entirely legal?)

Comment: You mean to say two NIC cards and two static IP's from your ISP and assign them to different NIC cards?

Comment: @Calm Storm: it isn't illegal, but the sysadmin is in its right to throttle or block you if you are not polite (like trying to refresh every 40 seconds, constantly).

Comment: @voyager I get that. My point is "downvoting" should be used for badly framed questions (not wrong kind of questions). If this question is illegal then this should be marked for deletion (and not downvoted ?)

Comment: @calm storm crawling website isn't illegal per se, calling it "scraping" makes it highly doubtful though.

Comment: You could easily rephrase this question as to how to specify the origin IP of a request in commons-httpcore. There are valid used for this that are unrelated to webscraping and its moral objectionability

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3528/38765

Answer (score 2):

```
// requires HttpComponents Client 4.*
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(
  ConnRoutePNames.LOCAL_ADDRESS, 
  InetAddress.getByName("10.10.10.10")
);
```

See: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/httpclient/apidocs/index.html

Comment: This would only work if the server is naive enough to throttle-by-IP based on the IP placed in the http headers by the client. In other words: unlikely.

Comment: Most well written applications have some netscalars/or some router config where they "physically" actually look up your IP address (and not what you set on the headers field). I work in the gambling industry and it is a legal requirement to do this (to block bets from some countries)

Comment: @david I think you've mixed some httpclient 3.x with 4.x there @matt @calm using `ConnRoutePNames.LOCAL_ADDRESS` doesn't set any header but actually allows to set the IP address to use (internally using `Socket.bind(SocketAddress)`).